# "What place is this?" vs "What is this place?"

Tags: british-english

Are they different? To me it seems that there is no difference at all, an they are merely constructed differently.

Comment: Please provide some context.

Comment: Do you mean in the following contexts: <I>I want to know what the place is</I> <I>I want to know what is the place</I>

Comment: They seem totally different to me. The first one I read as like asking for naming a place in a picture/photo, whereas the second one asks for confirmation that one is in a brothel (having expected a pub).

Answer (score 4):

**Brief intro and background**

I do agree that both seem very similar, but as Google Ngrams shows, "What is this place?" is far more *modern* and has increased in usage since about the mid-to-late 1900s.

[image]

**What is this place?**

This expression is commonly used to convey awe, horror, or astonishment regarding one's surroundings. Suppose, for instance, that you and your friends stumble upon an ancient tomb underneath your familiar city.

> "What is this place?" she wondered, her eyes wide with amazement.

**What place is this?**

Again, you don't commonly hear this spoken, as people typically say "Where are we?" or "Where am I?" Unlike the previous expression, this question is more concerned with asking, and eliciting a genuine response, as to where one is located. But I'm guessing it may have been equivalent in meaning to "What is this place" in older times, such as the 1800s.

Comment: I LIKE IT: google Ngrams greatly strengthens your answer!